# Optimal allocation in network

Tags: calculus, probability, graph-theory, optimization, network

We want to analyse specialization matters in a given network (N,g).

Nodes represent individuals that can produce goods and services (just like in our usual economy) and that can be consumers too.

This problem studies optimal production allocation:

- We suppose that individual need at most $\alpha$ kind of good or service per time (t) (in futher problem, we will analyse the case in which $\alpha$ is stochastic).
- Goods are evaluated in terms of quantities, and services in terms of hours (hours allocated for their production). So $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^+$.
- At each time t, individual $j$ ask for a quantity $q_i^j$ for a specific kind of good or services $i$ with probability $p_j$.

**The question is :** how many kind of good or service each individual (node) has to product, and in which quantity, in order to give satisfaction  to all the network at each  moment t?

Moreover, we suppose that each individual can product at least $E(\frac{\alpha}{N})$ kind of goods/services each time (t).

Comment: @DavidMitra In view of [this meta thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/what-is-the-site-etiquette-about-i-asking-and-ii-answering-questions-in-a-la), I thought it was ok to post questions in other languages...

Comment: Bienvenue sur ce site ! Je n'arrive pas à comprendre l'énoncé de votre question.  Plus précisément, je ne parviens pas à en extraire le sens mathématique.  Qu'est-ce qu'un agent ? un individu inactif ? une demande $q_i$ ? une quantitié de production ? $\alpha$ est-il un nombre entier ou réel ? Il sera plus facile pour quelqu'un de répondre à votre question si vous en clarifiez l'énoncé.  (J'ajoute que, bien qu'il ne soit pas interdit de poser des questions dans une langue autre que l'anglais, cela risque fort de réduire les chances qu'on vous réponde).

Comment: I put it in english, i hope that i make clear than the last one.